# creacion de directorios con fopen en c++ y linux

Tags: c++, archivo, fopen

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo binario con rutas ingresadas por el usuario, me salta un error 10598 segmentation fault (core dumped) al ingresar de ejemplo la ruta: /home/user/Disco1.dsk, en todo caso necesito que cree el directorio si este no existe.
Estoy usando un sistema linux.
Este es el codigo que tengo escrito:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Ingresar Ruta: "<<endl;
    string ruta;
    getline(cin,ruta);
    FILE *archivo = fopen(ruta.c_str(),"wb");
    char k[1024]="";
    fseek(archivo,0,SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&k,sizeof(k),1,archivo);
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

he realizado pruebas, pero solo me permite crearlo si esta dentro del directorio relativo con una carpeta ya creada pero no me funciona si esta fuera de el directorio relativo y no funciona dentro del directorio relativo si no esta creada la carpeta, ejemplo:
./proyecto/binarios/binari.dsk
proyecto seria la carpeta relativa donde estaria el main, el programa funciona si la carpeta binarios existe de lo contrario no funcionaria y si esta fuera de esta ruta no funciona. Les agreadezco por su ayuda de antemano

Comment: La creación del directorio si éste no existe no es posible haciendo uso de `fopen()`. El problema que tienes con tu código es que nunca compruebas si el valor de `archivo` es `NULL` tras una apertura fallida del archivo. No deberías dejar de hacer ese tipo de comprobaciones. Además, para crear directorios debes usar explícitamente la función [`mkdir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda voy a modificar mi codigo de esta forma.

Comment: `string.h` contiene funciones de C. Para usar la librería de strings de C++ incluye `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [`create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) desde C++17 en adelante.

La función se encuentra en el namespace `std::filesystem`.

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main(){   
    std::filesystem::create_directories("d1/d2/d3/d4/d5");
    return 0;
}
```

Creará las carpetas `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4` y `d5` o las que falten.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda